# BIRT - Multiple Trendlines and dynamic series in scatter chart

Tags: charts, birt, scatter-plot

I need to create a scatter chart in BIRT with several conditions:

1. I have a data set with several dozen records. The rows of the dataset represent the Y-Value on the scatter chart. I have a column "CLEANING_DATE" in my dataset. Several rows can have the same CLEANING_DATE which is okay, all the data is correct.
2. Records should be split between cleaning dates. Example table:

   ID | VALUE | CLEANING DATE | VALUE_DATE

   1  |  83  |    2013-02-01  |    2013-02-02 
   1  |  84  |    2013-02-01  |    2013-02-03
   1  |  85  |    2013-02-01  |    2013-02-04
   1  |  86  |    2013-02-01  |    2013-02-05

   1  |  84  |    2013-02-06  |    2013-02-06
   1  |  85  |    2013-02-06  |    2013-02-07
   1  |  86  |    2013-02-06  |    2013-02-08

   1 |   82  |    2013-02-09    |  2013-02-09
   1 |   83  |    2013-02-09    |  2013-02-10
   1 |   84  |    2013-02-09    |  2013-02-11
   1 |   85  |    2013-02-09    |  2013-02-12
   1 |   86  |    2013-02-09    |  2013-02-13
3. Explanation: Each VALUE represents a performance value. Each day, the performance drops (the values increase, because it's a slip formula). After a few days, a cleaning takes place which is good for the performance.
4. What I need is a scatter chart with all the entries, but I also need a trendline for **each**  of the parts, meaning, I need a separate trendline for each section between the respective cleaning dates.
5. For better explanation, I uploaded a screenshot.

[Screenshot of sample](http://picpaste.com/sample-kahWE1Rw.png)

1. For the linear trendline, I use a script in the onRender() section of the chart.

Could anybody give me some hints how to do this? I have tried grouping the values, which makes the scatters look good but the thing with trendline doesn't work properly.

Comment: I have done some more research and found out how to add series to the chart. 

What I'm still stuck is on how to dynamically add the data to those series, (i need a new series vor all values with the same cleaning date). 

Any hints? Thanks

Comment: Another update: I am able to create th series dynamically now. The only thinkg left is, that I cannot access the values of a chart series. Does anybody have a hint how to do that? I browsed the API docs for hours now, still no success :(